# Returning the updated variable passing through private methods

Tags: java

I noticed a scenario today. When we pass a parameter on private methods, the entity will return the revised values but not primitives.

Here is my sample code,

```
/**
 * @author gowthami
 *
 */
public class Test {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String s = "gowth";
        System.out.println("before " + s);
        concateMe(s, "ami");
        System.out.println("after " + s);

        BeanTest bt = new BeanTest();
        bt.setId("1");
        System.out.println("before");
        System.out.println(bt.getId());
        System.out.println(bt.getName());
        setBeanTestName(bt, "gowthami");
        System.out.println("after");
        System.out.println(bt.getId());
        System.out.println(bt.getName());

        String st = new String("gowth");
        System.out.println("before " + st);
        concateMe(st, "ami");
        System.out.println("after " + st);

    }

    private static void setBeanTestName(BeanTest bt, String string) {
        bt.setName(string);

    }

    private static void concateMe(String s, String string) {
        s = s+string;
        System.out.println("inside method " + s);
    }

}
```

BeanTest.java

```
public class BeanTest {

    private String id;
    private String name;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }


}
```

So the bean is getting updated even though we are not returning it from private method but a string is not. Can someone explain me whats happening on JVM level?

Comment: `String` is **immutable**.

Comment: ... compare with `StringBuilder` (which is mutable; that is **not *immutable***).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because Java follows **Call by value**, not **Call by reference**.

When you are passing **s** you are actually passing value of s, not the actual s. So though you are changing **s** in concateMe(), it will not change in your main method.

When you are passing **bt**, then the change is affecting as you are changing the field variable of that reference. But if you change the reference, then there will be no effect. You can add this in main method:

```
 System.out.println("before......");
 System.out.println(bt.getId());
 System.out.println(bt.getName());
 changeBeanTest(bt);
 System.out.println("after");
 System.out.println(bt.getId());
 System.out.println(bt.getName());
```

Suppose your **changeBeanTest** is like this:

```
private static void changeBeanTest(BeanTest tempBeanTest) { 
    BeanTest bt = new BeanTest();
    bt.setId("2");
    bt.setName("Trump");
    tempBeanTest = bt;
}
```

run this. There will be no change to **bt** sent from main().

Answer (score 0):

The Bean is a full object in java passed by reference to the private method so it is the same instance in the main method and the private method.

You are modifying the values of that instance so the changes show up in both places.

The string is more or less a primitive and passed as a copy of the value instead of the exact instance from main. It is a new instance in the private method and so you are modifying a new variable. The changes don't show up in the main method as it is a different entity.

Comment: There is no pass by reference in Java. The String is passed in exactly the same way as the bean (i.e. as a copy of the value of the pointer to a heap object), the difference is that a String is immutable whereas the bean is not. Doing something like  `bean = new Bean(bean.name + c)` (just like  `s = s + string`) does not change the caller's variable value either.

Answer (score 0):

String s = "gowth"; in this line s is pointing to "gowth" from String Pool.When you are calling
private static void concateMe(String s, String string) here String s is different from caller method String s.Here String s scope is local to method ContactMe,But contactMe local String s pointing same "gowth" which is pointed by Caller class String s.After s = s + string;since String is immutable the method local reference String s pointing a different String "gowthami",but caller method String s is still pointing to "gowth".So you are getting this output.
But in case of Bean both the object pointing same String reference,Once we made any change in reference it would be reflected for both object.